# How to make nixos container visible to the external network

Tags: networking, nixos, linux-containers

I'd like to have a nixos container that is visible to the outside network.  I'd like to setup a static IP for that container that some other laptop on my network at home can ssh into the container.  The container should be accessible to more than just the host it resides on.  So lets label these computers.  (A) is the nixos host.  (B) is the container residing on (A).  And (C) is a third separate computer on the network that wants to access (B) over the network.  If someone could provide the simplest configuration that should be added to the `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file to achieve this that would be tremendously appreciated.

```
                                 +-------------------+
+--------+                       |                   |
|        |                       |  +--------+     A |
|      C |                       |  |        |       |
|   +----------------------------------->  B |       |
|        |                       |  |        |       |
+--------+                       |  |        |       |
                                 |  +--------+       |
                                 |                   |
                                 |                   |
                                 +-------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete danbst answer, for the option 2 you can use the container option `privateNetwork = false;` to disable the network namespace.
[See container.nix code](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/2456e8475ffd7363fe194505ef0488dfc89a8eb1/nixos/modules/virtualisation/containers.nix#L494) for details. With this option you will share the same IP address between the host and the container.

An other option is to forward port from the container to the host with [ForwardPorts options](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/2456e8475ffd7363fe194505ef0488dfc89a8eb1/nixos/modules/virtualisation/containers.nix#L326).

A more generic way (that works with NixOps too) it to use the host `networking.nat` option, for example:

```
networking.nat = {
    enable=true;
    internalInterfaces=["ve-+"];
    externalInterface = "enp0s3";
    forwardPorts = [
      {destination = "mycontainerIP:80"; sourcePort = 80;}
    ];
  };
```

Comment: Note that `forwardPorts` only uses `DNAT`, i.e. it forwards the packet to the container without rewriting the source address. If your container uses special routing settings like a VPN tunnel you might need to add source NAT like this:
`networking.nat.extraCommands = ''iptables -t nat -A nixos-nat-post -d  ${container.localAdress} --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source ${container.hostAdress}''`. This way the package source will be rewritten to the host veth address to which the container will always know how to route to.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that, and all aren't NixOS specific here.

1. Organize a VPN between machines and containers. For example, launch OpenVPN master on your host and OpenVPN clients in containers and other machines. You will get a subnet where you can access your containers by separate IPs. Unfortunately, this requires lots of configuration (I've done this before).
2. Don't use separate virtual ethernet devices for containers. Then all containers will share host's port addresses and be equally accessible from outside. This requires port remapping for conflicting services though.
3. Proxy desired ports from host to container (I did this using `haproxy`)

Comment: The solution I'm looking for is that each container should have it's own unique ip address and it's full range of normal ports accessible on the local network.  For this reason I think option 3 would be out?  I don't think a VPN is required for this, so maybe no option 1? Perhaps the option 2 would work.  Can I assign different IP addresses so each machine has their own IP?  Could you provide a nix config file example of this?  Thank you so much already! :)